# Do the Mosaic Laws/Commandments need to be followed outside of Israel (or the Land God gave to the Israelites)?

Tags: history

Deuteronomy 12:1 seems very clear as to where the Laws/Statutes/Commands apply:

“These are the decrees and laws you must be careful to follow in the land that the Lord, the God of your ancestors, has given you to possess—as long as you live in the land.” (Deuteronomy 12:1)

So, is there a "legal" as opposed to a moral requirement to follow these in the rest of the world?

Comment: When it says "these", what indicates it's referring to the entire Mosaic Law?

Comment: For arguments sake [some commandments](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%9D&tab=text&tpathFilters=Tanakh&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance) explicitly state that they're to be followed in "all of your dwelling places".

Answer (score 2):

This question is addressed in the Gemara [Kiddushin 37A](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.37a.5?lang=bi):

> אָמַר רַב יְהוּדָה הָכִי קָאָמַר כׇּל מִצְוָה שֶׁהִיא חוֹבַת הַגּוּף נוֹהֶגֶת בֵּין בָּאָרֶץ בֵּין בְּחוּץ לָאָרֶץ חוֹבַת קַרְקַע אֵינָהּ נוֹהֶגֶת אֶלָּא בָּאָרֶץ

> Rav Yehuda said that this is what the mishna is saying: Any mitzva that is an obligation of the body, i.e., an obligation upon the person, applies both in Eretz Yisrael and outside of Eretz Yisrael. Conversely, an obligation of the land, that is, a mitzva that applies specifically to the earth and its growths, applies only in Eretz Yisrael.

> מְנָא הָנֵי מִילֵּי דְּתָנוּ רַבָּנַן אֵלֶּה הַחֻקִּים אֵלּוּ הַמִּדְרָשׁוֹת וְהַמִּשְׁפָּטִים אֵלּוּ הַדִּינִים אֲשֶׁר תִּשְׁמְרוּן זוֹ מִשְׁנָה לַעֲשׂוֹת זוֹ מַעֲשֶׂה

> The Gemara asks: From where are these matters derived? The Gemara answers: This is as the Sages taught in a baraita: The verse states: “These are the statutes and the ordinances that you shall observe to do in the land that the Lord, the God of your fathers, has given you to possess it, all the days that you live upon the earth” (Deuteronomy 12:1). This verse is interpreted as follows: The phrase “these are the statutes” means that these are the expositions that the Sages learn from verses. With regard to the phrase “and the ordinances,” these are monetary laws. With regard to “that you shall observe,” this is referring to the study of matters that must be observed for one to perform them. And as for the phrase “to do,” this is referring to action, the actual performance of mitzvot.

**בָּאָרֶץ יָכוֹל כׇּל הַמִּצְוֹת כּוּלָּן לֹא יְהוּ נוֹהֲגִים אֶלָּ בָּאָרֶץ תַּלְמוּד לוֹמַר כׇּל הַיָּמִים אֲשֶׁר אַתֶּם חַיִּים עַל הָאֲדָמָה אִי כׇּל הַיָּמִים יָכוֹל יְהוּ נוֹהֲגִים בֵּין בָּאָרֶץ בֵּין בְּחוּצָה לָאָרֶץ תַּלְמוּד לוֹמַר בָּאָרֶץ**

> The baraita continues: From the phrase “in the land [ba’aretz],” one might have thought that all mitzvot apply only in Eretz Yisrael. Therefore, the verse also states “all the days that you live upon the earth,” i.e., wherever you live. Furthermore, if the Merciful One had written only the phrase “all the days,” one might have thought that all mitzvot should apply both in Eretz Yisrael and outside of Eretz Yisrael. Therefore, the verse also states “in the land.”

אַחַר שֶׁרִיבָּה הַכָּתוּב וּמִיעֵט צֵא וּלְמַד מִמַּה שֶּׁאָמוּ בָּעִנְיָן אַבֵּד תְּאַבְּדוּן אֶת כׇּל הַמְּקֹמוֹת אֲשֶׁר עָבְדוּ שָׁם וְגוֹ' מָה עֲבוֹדָה זָרָה מְיוּחֶדֶת שֶׁהִיא חוֹבַת הַגּוּף וְנוֹהֶגֶת בֵּין בָּאָרֶץ בֵּין בְּחוּצָה לָאָרֶץ אַף כֹּל שֶׁהִיא חוֹבַת הַגּוּף נוֹהֶגֶת בֵּין בָּאָרֶץ בֵּין בְּחוּצָה לָאָרֶץ

> The baraita continues: Once the verse includes areas outside of Eretz Yisrael and also excludes areas outside of Eretz Yisrael, how is it determined which mitzvot apply outside the land and which do not? The baraita answers: Go and learn from what is stated with regard to a different issue that appears in the next verse: “You shall destroy all the places where the nations that you are to dispossess served their gods” (Deuteronomy 12:2). Just as the prohibition of idol worship is distinct in that it is an obligation of the body, and it applies both in Eretz Yisrael and outside of Eretz Yisrael, so too, any mitzva that is an obligation of the body applies both in Eretz Yisrael and outside of Eretz Yisrael. Conversely, mitzvot that are an obligation connected to the land apply only in Eretz Yisrael.

Answer (score 0):

The Ramban writes on Vayikra 18:25,

> ומן הענין הזה אמרו בספרי (עקב מג) ואבדתם מהרה (דברים יא יז) **אף על פי שאני מגלה אתכם מן הארץ לחוצה לארץ היו מצויינין במצות שכשתחזרו לא יהו עליכם חדשים** משל לאדון שכעס על אשתו ושלחה לבית אביה אמר לה הוי מתקשטת תכשיטים שכשתחזרי לא יהיו עליך חדשים...והנה הכתוב שאמר (דברים יא יז-יח) ואבדתם מהרה ושמתם את דברי אלה וגו' **אינו מחייב בגלות אלא בחובת הגוף כתפילין ומזוזות ופירשו בהן כדי שלא יהו חדשים עלינו כשנחזור לארץ** **כי עיקר כל המצות ליושבים בארץ ה'** ולפיכך אמרו בספרי (ראה פ) וירשתם אותה וישבתם בה ושמרתם לעשות (דברים יא לא-לב) ישיבת ארץ ישראל שקולה כנגד כל המצות שבתורה

This oft quoted Ramban says that the purpose of most mitzvos in chutz la'aretz is simply in order to remain in touch with them so that when the galus ends they aren't new to us. Rashi says the same thing in his comment to Devarim 11:18. Their comments are based on the Sifri Parshas Eikev (43:17). No one seems to talk about that Rashi, I don't know why. Also, [this page](https://www.sefaria.org.il/sheets/232195?lang=he) on sefaria might be helpful, as well as [this website](https://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/taleley/kiyum-2.htm). The second link is much, much more thorough, both of them are only in hebrew.

I hope this was helpful.